# Variation of a Probability Integral Transform

Tags: probability

I'm struggling with the following problem. If $Y$ is a continuous random variable, then obviously (probability integral transform) $F_Y(Y) \sim Unif(0,1)$ is true. Hence the expected value is $E\left[F_Y(Y)\right] = 0.5$. I'm now trying to show that the following also holds true:
$$ E\left[F_Y\left(\frac{Y}{\sigma}\right)\right] = 0.5$$
**My approach to do this went as follows:**
If we define $V = F_Y\left(\frac{Y}{\sigma}\right)$, we need to show that $F_V(v) = v$, since this is the CDF of a standard uniform, which implies an expectation of 0.5. I've thus attempted to use a probability integral transform here as well and ended up with the following:
$$ F_V(v) = F_Y(\sigma F_Y^{-1}(v)) $$
This is as far as I got since that $\sigma$ prevents me from taking advantage of the fact that I have both the cdf and its inverse. Can someone give a nudge in the right direction? I'm also open to completely different approaches obviously :) Thanks.